# what is the value for second parameter for getdevicecaps function?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am trying to get the physical margins of an active printer. But i am not sure what should i give the values for second parameter for GetDeviceCaps function. Can someone tell me what are the values for **HORZSIZE** and **VERTSIZE** i can set to get the actual printer values.

if i am using 0 as value for second parameter i am getting getX and getY values as 1024. Can someone please help me.

**Note:** DefaultPrinterInfo is a user defined function to get the drivername and printername

```
Sub GetDevCaps()
    Dim str() As String
    Dim hdc As Long, delHdc As Long
    Dim getX As Long, getY As Long
    str = DefaultPrinterInfo
    hdc = CreateDC(str(1), str(0), 0, 0)
    getX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, ?)
    getY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, ?)
    delHdc = DeleteDC(hdc)<br>
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter indicates the information you want to retrieve. You can find the constants and an explanation in this [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/114709/en-us) article.

The constants you have been asking for:

```
Global Const HORZSIZE = 4
Global Const VERTSIZE = 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I have few questions here.. why it is 4 and 6 and what actually it means? When i replace with 4 and 6 i am getting getX= 198 and getY= 287. Are these values are in pixel. I want to convert these into mm. Thanks once again. Ramana

Comment: The following article might give you additional help: http://mollyrocket.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1940   I understand that the values are in pixels. If you need Inches, you should look at LOGPIXELSX=88 and LOGPIXELSY=90